# PHP scandir filtrado por nome

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer um scandir de um diretório que será filtrado por uma variável que contém o nome do arquivo (sem a extensão) porém não tenho idéia de como realizar isso, segue um exemplo:

```
$nome = $_POST["imgname"];//nome do arquivo recebido pelo post
$dir = "pasta/img/";//Local onde o arquivo está salvo
$arquivo = scandir($dir);//Pedaço que gostaria de modificar para filtrar pelo $nome
```

**OBS:** Estou fazendo o scandir para conseguir a extensão do arquivo pois como falei acima a variável `$nome` não possui extensão, se houver outra forma de conseguir o nome completo do arquivo especificado ajudaria muito também!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer `glob("{$dir}/{$nome}*");`, assim você poderá capturar o arquivo. Ex:

```
~/Images
    01.jpg
    02.jpg
    03.jpg
    04.jpg
    05.jpg
    05.png
```

**Php:**

```
<?php

var_dump( glob("~/Images/01*") );

//Output
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "~/Images/01.jpg"
}
```

Com o `glob` (eu) acho mais simples, mas é possível com `scandir` também. Para isso basta utilizar  função [array_filter](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)

```
<?php

$files = scandir(__DIR__);

function checkFile($file) {
    return preg_match("/^{$_POST['name']}/", $file);
}

var_dump( array_filter($files, 'checkFile') );

//Output:
array(1) {
  [18]=>
  string(6) "~/Images/01.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Mais simples do que pensei, obrigado pela dica, porém porque colocou {} nas variáveis? Pelo que testei ele me retornou o mesmo valor com ou sem elas, tem algum motivo específico?

Comment: @Wel apenas para melhorar a leitura e para não ficar utilizando `"texto" . $var . "texto"`. Isso me permite utilizar `"texto{$var}text"`, assim o PHP saberá o limite da variável. Caso não existissem o `{}`, o PHP acharia que a variável é `$vartext`.